# PHP Increment with 2 adjacent foreach() don't work

Tags: php, loops, foreach, increment

```
<?php
$x=0;
foreach($a as $b) {
    $x++;
    echo $x; // output 1 2 3 4 
    echo $b; // output a b c d
}
?>
<div>SOME HTML ELEMENTs</div>
<?PHP
foreach($c as $d) {
    $y=0;
    $y++;
    echo $y; // output 1 1 1 1 (should be 1 2 3 4!!!!);
    echo $d; // output e f g h
}
?>
```

Why $y will not increment?  but i can tell that the loop is working since i get the correct $d value to output.  can someone explain why this might be? I am burning my brain out.

Comment: If that's all the code you got then `echo $x;` will **not** print `1 2 3 4` but `1 1 1 1` since you reset it to 0 everytime you begin the loop.

Comment: I can't believe I am such an idiot! ... there goes my 1st post

Comment: If it makes you feel any better: We've all started somewhere and I've also seen **much** more unpleasant questions here on SO. Good luck on your project though! Oh.. and welcome to SO ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On every iteration, you are resetting `$y=0;`, causing it to always have the value of `1` at the echo. So move that out of the loop:

```
$y=0;
foreach($c as $d) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$x=0;
foreach($a as $b) {        
    $x++;
    echo $x;
    echo $b; 
}
?>
<div>SOME HTML ELEMENTs</div>
<?PHP
$y=0;
foreach($c as $d) {
    $y++;
    echo $y; 
    echo $d;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reseting `$x` & `$y` to `0` with each loop iteration.

```
foreach($a as $b) {
    $x=0;
    $x++;
    …

foreach($c as $d) {
    $y=0;
    $y++;
    …
```

Change it to this:

```
$x=0;
foreach($a as $b) {
    $x++;
    …

$y=0;
foreach($c as $d) {
    $y++;
    …
```